# How to execute ssh commands in an Android application

Tags: java, android, linux

Relatively new to this but, I was planning to write a simple android application which can run and execute simple terminal commads like ssh, change directories etc. But i want to create buttons for each command. so (cd..) command will be a button, (mkdir) will be another. The main idea is to connect to a Linux server and then execute these commands on them, I would also use some commands which start services or kill services.

I want to know if there is any class in Android which allows me to run these commands programmatically?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there is any class in Android which allows me to run these commands programmatically?.

No, unless you count `Socket`.

Instead, you would need to find an SSH client library for Android, or perhaps for ordinary Java (and hope that it runs unmodified on Android).